# Spring boot Request Mapping URI Patterns

Tags: java, spring-boot, request-mapping

There is a request mapping like this:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/{version:.+}")
```

I not sure what is the `.+` does, but from what i know, this delete mapping can accept a value and match to path variable `version`, something like:

```
DELETE
/abc
```

Value `abc` will map to path variable `version`

Why the `.+` is needed?

---

Edited Question:
What is the difference with just `/{version}`, is there any special case that requires `.+`?

Comment: .+ means "one or of more ANY character". Thats regex.

Comment: if i put `"/{version}"`, is there any difference?

Comment: Probably in some edge cases but not in generral.

Comment: @Antoniossss edge cases like?

Comment: @Kartik cases like version that has dot, if a version is 1.12.23, the dot will be truncated, with this regex, the entire `1.12.23` will be preserved.

Answer (score 4):

You can find details or URL matching on this link
[URL matching](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-mvc-url-matching)

**REGEX:** `.+` means one or more.
‘*’ Matches 0 or More Characters
'+' Matches 1 or More.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

`@DeleteMapping(value = "/{version:.+}")`

`.+` means "one or more of any characters" - thats standard regex/

`version:` means - put that match in path variable named version.